# Яке походження виразу "бути при надії" про вагітність? Чи можна вживати в літературній мові?

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

Словник [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nadija) подає це значення як "діалектне":

> ♦ Бути при надії, діал. — чекати родів (про вагітну жінку). — Як я була при надії, а він напитий прийшов, то й за волоси мене водив, і ще й кулакував (Лесь Мартович, Тв., 1954, 123).

"Мова - ДНК нації" пропонує використовувати цей вираз замість "[в цікавому стані](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/butu-pru-nadiyi)":

> P.S. "Бути в цікавому стані - калька"

Яке походження цього виразу? Чи можна використовувати його у літературній мові? Чи є якісь додаткові конотації ("в цікавому стані" на мій погляд іронічне)?

Comment: Цікаво, що [тут](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile.php?transfer=folders/o/ozidanij.html), як аналогічний російський вираз, наводять «быть в ожидании» — хоча в інших місцях я не бачу, щоб «быть в ожидании» (без пояснення чого саме) мало сталу конотацію «бути вагітною».

Comment: Як аналоги евфемістичному «в интересном положении» [тут](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile2.php?transfer=folders/b/beremennaja.html) наводять «*такою* бути», «в *такім* ділі бути», «на *таких* порах бути».

Comment: «Быть в интересном положение» є фактично інтернаціональним (фр. [état intéressant](//fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/état_intéressant), [position intéressante](//fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/position_intéressante) або [situation intéressante](//fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/situation_intéressante), англ. [interesting condition](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interesting_condition)) — і, хто перший, невідомо.

Comment: "[Декамерон](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1000149/105/Bokachcho_Dzhovanni_-_Dekameron.html)" у перекладі Миколи Лукаша містить вираз "при надії", та й у новинах [уживається](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/multimedia/2014/09/140908_royal_pregnancy_it)

Comment: @Sasha - [Ось пишуть](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=interesting&allowed_in_frame=0), що англійське _interesting condition_ вперше зафіксовано в 1748, то скоріше за все англійці були першими.

Comment: @YellowSky, так а про французів же нема даних?

Comment: @Sasha -Ну там за вашими посиланнями вказано словники десь року 1800.

Comment: Я оце щойно був дуже здивований, коли дізнався, що в українській є слово «роди».

Comment: @YellowSky, а звідки ж тоді, на вашу думку, походять слова *народжувати(ся)*, *народження*, *розродитися*, *уродини* (*вродини*) тощо?)

Comment: Ще є цікаве слово *породілля*.

Comment: *У того ж В. Даля з'являється поняття «зносити», в тому числі, у значенні терпіти. - І це теж хороший привід для роздумів. **А широко відомий оборот «бути при надії» пов'язаний зі швидкими пологами.** Підвищення сімейного статусу невістки чітко звучить і в такому у вислові: «Першого сина женять батько та мати, а другого - невістка»*  [(с)Знайдено в інтернеті(с)](http://arhiv-statey.pp.ua/index.php?newsid=22495) Тобто, після пологів статус невістки у родині свекрухи і свекра значно покращувався. Звідси і надія на це.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Словник Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/30200-nadija.html#show_point) уточнює, що вираз цей поширений на Волині:

> бу́ти при наді́ї. Быть беременной, ожидать родовъ. Волынь.

Також подібний вираз [наявний](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=8DOuBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=uk#v=snippet&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%97%22&f=false) у німецькій, польській та іспанській мовах. Польською *"być przy nadziei"* та німецькою *"guter Hoffnung sein"*, *"in der Hoffnung sein"*; іспанською [*"estar en estado de buena esperanza"*](https://browse.dict.cc/spanisch-deutsch/estar+en+estado+de+buena+esperanza.html).

[Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=guter+Hoffnung+sein&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_varianten_ou) каже, що це й вираз у німецькій з 18 століття і є застарілим.

Отже можна припустити, що в українську мову виарз *"бути при надії"* у значенні "бути вагітною" прийшов з німецької через польську.

---

Зазначу, що [Словник українських синонімів](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=5g4aAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%97%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%97%22&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi91dqN4fPcAhXpBZoKHb-ABGI4ChDoAQgzMAM) пропонує низку синонімічних виразів:

> ***в делікатному стані; в очікуванні; в тяжі; в тязі; на останніх днях; при надії; у ваготі; у вазі; ось-ось розсиплеться; скоро буде мамою; увійшла в тяж; у стані; у повіжному стані; у тяготі; у тяжі; у тяжу; ходить важкою; ходить дитиною; ходить на вазі; ходить на останніх днях; ходить при надії; ходить тяжкою.